# Error while deleting sheet. Runtime Error 1004 : delete method of range class failed

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to delete a sheet selected from a list box. The msgbox commands displaying the sheet names are correct but I seem to get an error which is as below:

Runtime Error 1004: Delete method of range class failed.

Here is my code.

```
If ListBox2.Selected(i) Then
        Worksheets(ListBox2.List(i)).Unprotect "asdf"
        Worksheets(ListBox2.List(i)).Delete
        MsgBox ListBox2.List(i)
        sht = ListBox2.List(i) + "_Graph"
        Worksheets(sht).Unprotect "asdf"
        MsgBox sht
        Worksheets(sht).Delete
        Worksheets("Report").Rows(ListBox2.ListIndex + 2).Delete
        MsgBox "KC " + ListBox2.List(i) + " Removed!"

    End If
```

Comment: you have three lines that use the `delete` method, and you could not be bothered to tell us which line is failing .... and the last command is a `msgbox` command ..... since you said that the msgbox commands display the correct sheet names, no none of the `delete` methods in the code are failing.  ... your problem is someplace else

Comment: The problem is in the second to last line - there you use `Delete` method on `Range` object.

Comment: Any autofilter or sheet protection on your "Report" sheet?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Worksheets("Report").Rows(ListBox2.ListIndex + 2).EntireRow.Delete
```

instead of:

```
Worksheets("Report").Rows(ListBox2.ListIndex + 2).Delete
```

(second to last line).